# How to install clang 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, installation, clang, ubuntu-12.04

I want to install clang 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04. How can I do that?

I am trying this but It couldn't find package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.6
[sudo] password for xristina: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'clang-3.6'
```

Comment: This gist may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/craigminihan/229b0ee9dcf4ab6d794c4c8ee1f0d92e

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rebuild them.

Good luck